# Leading Zero with Datestamp in SSIS Expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, substring

I'm trying to format a datestamp to have leading zeros in an expression using SSIS 2008 R2.

My desired result would be `Exceptions - YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.xls` so as an example, now would be:

```
\\SomePath\Exceptions - 20150211155745.xls
```

I am having an issue adding the leading zeros to the day and month though.

I've tried the following expressions by trying to convert to `DT_WSTR` with the length set as well as picking the date apart usg `SUBSTRING`:

```
@[User::XLFileRootDir] + "Exceptions - " + (DT_WSTR, 4) DATEPART("YYYY", GETDATE()) + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("MM", GETDATE()) + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("DD", GETDATE())  + ".xls"
```

This results in `\\SomePath\Exceptions - 2015211155745.xls` (notice the missing leading zero on the month).

```
@[User::XLFileRootDir] + "Exceptions - " + (DT_WSTR, 4) SUBSTRING(GETDATE(), 1, 4) + ".xls"
```

This results in an error as the data type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` isn't supported by the function `SUBSTRING`. I'm aware that some sort of conversion needs to take place but can't find a function within SSIS to complete this.

Could anyone help me with how to format the expression with leading zeros?

Comment: Each place you call GETDATE(), cast it as a string.

Comment: @TabAlleman `CAST` isn't a recognised function in SSIS (it's not `T-SQL`)

Comment: Well, I didn't mean you should use the function CAST(), I meant you should CAST it as a string using the tools that are available in your environment.  CAST may be a specific function in SQL, but it is also a generic programming term meaning change the datatype of something.  In an SSIS expression, you perform a CAST by preceding it with the datatype in parens, like you're already doing before "DATEPART" in your first code block.

Comment: @TabAlleman Ah figured out what you mean and have got it working with `SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR, 29) GETDATE(), 1, 4)`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that the YEAR/MONTH/DAY functions return an integer. An integer won't present leading zeros. Therefore, the "trick" is to convert it to a string. Prepend a leading zero to that string. Then, shear off the last 2 characters using the `RIGHT` function. The trimming is only required for October, November, and December but the logic is cleaner to unconditionally apply `RIGHT`.

This builds your YYYYMMDD string.

```
(DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(@[System::StartTime]) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(@[System::StartTime]), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[System::StartTime]), 2)
```

I find it better to use the variable `System::StartTime` rather than `GETDATE()`, especially when time is involved. GETDATE will be evaluated each time it is inspected. Over long running packages, there can be a sizable drift in the values returned. System::StartTime is the time the package itself began. It is constant for the run itself but obviously resets *per* run.

Comment: Great thanks and duly noted about using `System::StartTime` over `GETDATE()`

Comment: In fact I want to thank you again as you've just solved another problem due to me using `GETDATE()`!

Answer (score 2):

For my application, I needed the exact current time, and I needed it down to the second, which yielded this:

```
(DT_WSTR, 4)DATEPART("yyyy",GETDATE()) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("mm",GETDATE()),2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("dd",GETDATE()),2)
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("Hh",GETDATE()),2)
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("mi",GETDATE()),2)
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("s",GETDATE()),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR, 29) GETDATE(), 6, 2)
```