# Get Filename of Timestamped CSV using C# Script in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on an SSIS package that loads data from a CSV file into a staging table in SQL Server. The CSV file will be in the following format:

```
FILENAME_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.csv
```

The YYMMDD portion will always correspond to yesterday's date, but the HHMMSS piece will vary depending on exactly when the CSV file was created.

Is there a way to use a script component in SSIS to do the following:

1. Check to see if there was a file written yesterday (YYYYMMDD = yesterday's date)
2. If so, store the full filename to a variable

Comment: Are you set on having to do this with a Script Task? Expression + Foreach File enumerator handles this quite well

Comment: No, I'm not set on Script and am willing to consider any options. I'm very new to SSIS, can you elaborate how to implement the Foreach file enumerator?

Comment: You might want to consider what happens if you'r package fails to run for one day... you'll miss a file. It's better to not build logic around these kind of assumptions. I suggest you use a series of folders to manage if a file has been imported or not. i.e. files land in a folder called 'landing', every time the package runs it processes everything in 'landing' (regardless of datestamp). Once complete files are moved to 'complete'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this as an application of other answers

- YYYYMMDD pattern [Leading Zero with Datestamp in SSIS Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458910/leading-zero-with-datestamp-in-ssis-expression/28459183#28459183)
- Foreach pattern [How to import text files with the same name and schema but different directories into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957451/how-to-import-text-files-with-the-same-name-and-schema-but-different-directories/19957728#19957728)

The first link shows how we'd use an expression to build out a YYYYMMDD string. You need yesterday's date so I'd extend that answer by either applying `dateadd("dd", -1, @[System::StartTime)` 3 times or I'd add a third Variable, Yesterday and then reference it. In this answer, I will add the Yesterday variable and use it.

The second link covers using a Foreach (file) enumerator. The loop takes as `FileSpec` filter. We'll use a Variable to hold this value and that Variable will have an expression applied

```
"FILENAME_" + @[User::YYYYMMDD]+ "_*.csv"
```

That's our hard coded file name with the Variable we created in the first step and then an an asterisk to handle the variable time component.

When the foreach loop runs, it's going to populate the fully qualified path name into a variable called `CurrentFileName`

We use *that* as an Expression on our Flat File Connection Manager to point it to the correct file prior to import.

It looks like a lot but once you play with it, it shouldn't seem so bad.

[image]

### Biml

The biml to create this package is nearly identical to the one posted on the second linked post. The place to look changes is the expression for the FileSpec.

How do you use this?

- Put a file out at C:\ssisdata\so\TEST\201306\sample1.txt (or fix all references to that to be somewhere else)

File should look like

```
ID,value
1,text here
```

- Install [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) Free add-on to improve your BI life
- In an IS project, right click on the project and add a new biml file
- Double click BimlScript.biml and add the contents below replacing everything
- Save
- Right click on the BimlScript.biml file and select Generate SSIS package

Profit

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <!-- Create a basic flat file source definition -->
    <FileFormats>
        <FlatFileFormat
            Name="FFFSrc"
            CodePage="1252"
            RowDelimiter="CRLF"
            IsUnicode="false"
            FlatFileType="Delimited"
            ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="true"
        >
            <Columns>
                <Column
                    Name="ID"
                    DataType="Int32"
                    Delimiter=","
                    ColumnType="Delimited"
                />
                <Column
                    Name="value"
                    DataType="AnsiString"
                    Delimiter="CRLF"
                    InputLength="20"
                    MaximumWidth="20"
                    Length="20"
                    CodePage="1252"
                    ColumnType="Delimited"
                    />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
    </FileFormats>

    <!-- Create a connection that uses the flat file format defined above-->
    <Connections>
        <FlatFileConnection
            Name="FFSrc"
            FileFormat="FFFSrc"
            FilePath="C:\ssisdata\so\TEST\201306\sample1.txt"
            DelayValidation="true"
        />
    </Connections>

    <!-- Create a package to illustrate how to apply an expression on the Connection Manager -->
    <Packages>
        <Package
            Name="so_29480267"
            ConstraintMode="Linear"
        >
            <Connections>
                <Connection ConnectionName="tempdb"/>
                <Connection ConnectionName="FFSrc">
                    <Expressions>
                        <!-- Assign a variable to the ConnectionString property. 
                        The syntax for this is ConnectionManagerName.Property -->
                        <Expression PropertyName="FFSrc.ConnectionString">@[User::CurrentFileName]</Expression>
                    </Expressions>
                </Connection>
            </Connections>

            <!-- Create a single variable that points to the current file -->
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="CurrentFileName" DataType="String">C:\ssisdata\so\TEST\201306\sample1.txt</Variable>
                <Variable Name="Yesterday" DataType="DateTime" EvaluateAsExpression="true">DATEADD("dd", -1, @[System::StartTime])</Variable>
                <Variable Name="YYYYMMDD" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true">(DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(@[User::Yesterday]) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(@[User::Yesterday]), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[User::Yesterday]), 2)</Variable>
                <Variable Name="FileMask" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true">"FILENAME_" + @[User::YYYYMMDD]+ "_*.csv"</Variable>
                <Variable Name="SourceFolder" DataType="String">C:\ssisdata\so\TEST</Variable>
                <Variable Name="RowCountInput" DataType="Int32">0</Variable>
                <Variable Name="TargetTable" DataType="String">[dbo].[so_29480267]</Variable>
            </Variables>

            <!-- Add a foreach file enumerator. Use the above -->
            <Tasks>

                <ForEachFileLoop
                    Name="FELC Consume files"
                    FileSpecification="*.csv"
                    ProcessSubfolders="true"
                    RetrieveFileNameFormat="FullyQualified"
                    Folder="C:\"
                    ConstraintMode="Linear"
                >
                    <!-- Define the expressions to make the input folder and the file mask 
                    driven by variable values -->
                    <Expressions>
                        <Expression PropertyName="Directory">@[User::SourceFolder]</Expression>
                        <Expression PropertyName="FileSpec">@[User::FileMask]</Expression>
                    </Expressions>
                    <VariableMappings>
                        <!-- Notice that we use the convention of User.Variable name here -->
                        <VariableMapping
                            Name="0"
                            VariableName="User.CurrentFileName"
                        />
                    </VariableMappings>
                    <Tasks>
                        <Dataflow Name="DFT Import file" DelayValidation="true">
                            <Transformations>
                                <FlatFileSource Name="FFS Sample" ConnectionName="FFSrc"/>
                                <RowCount Name="RC Source" VariableName="User.RowCountInput"/>
                            </Transformations>
                        </Dataflow>
                    </Tasks>
                </ForEachFileLoop>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```